# Node Error: EADDRINUSE, how do I find out what process is locking this address?

Tags: node.js, apache, express, port

I have a test app using express that crashes on `server.listen(80)`: `ERROR: listen EADDRINUSE`. I tried to kill all node processes with `killall -9 node` but there were no processes. I also have apache running on the same server but I've got two IPs and I have configured apache to serve only one of them and yesterday everything worked fine. Some process is blocking port 80 on IP reserved for node and it's not node. What should I do?

**UPDATE**

That was my own lame mistake. I defined `node_ip` and `node_port` but accidently omitted `node_ip` in `server.listen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to see it first, you can use netstat, e.g.

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 80
```

Comment: As a side note, if you're running Apache, it's probably Apache that's using port 80, unless you changed its' config to not use it.

Comment: On OSX, I get `netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol` :(

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
 lsof -i :80
```

to see what process is running on that port.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tcpkill ie.:

```
tcpkill -i eth0 port 80
```